# Powershell - Skip if there are not folders or not folders older than 30 days

Tags: powershell

Thank you in advance!
I hope someone can help me with the following.  I can find the folders older than 30 days and the subfolders (as you can see in the script), but I want to add 2 functionalities.

- If there are not subfolders it has to skip.
- If there are not subfolders older than 30 days, it has to skip.

I was able to add the following condition "If there is not file with the name OwnerEmail.txt, it will skip"

```
if (-not(Test-Path $path)){Continue}
```

Thank you so much for all your help.
below is the script

```
$InitialFolder = "C:\Test\WRA"
$Sender = "cubam1@company.com"
$SenderReportFile = "C:\Test\WRA\file.csv"
# ==============================================


$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $InitialFolder -Directory | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($SubFolder in $ParentFolders) {
    $path = Join-Path $SubFolder -ChildPath 'OwnerEmail.txt'
    
# ================ If OwnerEmail.txt does not exist, skip ================
    if (-not(Test-Path $path)){Continue}


# ================ Building HTML Report ================
$WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime |
..
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: @Daniel Please post this as answer so the OP can accept it, marking this question 'Done'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if there are NOT subfolders older than 30 days and skip you can use

```
if (-not($SubFolder.GetDirectories() | 
    Where-Object CreationTime -LT (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30))) { continue }
```